# メッシュを変形させた箇所に影が出る

Tags: unity3d

お世話になります。
ZBrushでモデリングした物をMayaにexportし、ジョイントを入れ、変形させます。
その変形させたメッシュをUnityにexportすると画像のように変形させた箇所に影が出てしまいます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
face normalの向きは正常に外側に向いています。
Shaderは両方ともstandard shaderです。
lightはシーン内に一つもありません。
albedoを張った場合でも同じようになります。

この問題の原因と解決方法を模索しております。
どなたかお分かりになられる方がいらっしゃいましたら教えて頂けますと幸いです。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: モデルのimport settingでNormalをcalculateにしたら直りました。

Comment: お疲れ様です。よろしければ[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)していただけませんか？

Answer (score 1):

モデルのimport settingでNormalをcalculateにしたら直りました。